# Prestashop module off

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating my first blog for prestashop so far I'm getting to do what I wanted, so I came to a problem that I can not solve:

The module needs an api key to work, the issue is that I can give a warning if this api key does not exist, what I can not do is to disconnect the module, so I use it to understand that something is missing.

```
if (!Configuration::get('API_KEY')){
    $this->warning = $this->l('No api key provided');
}else{
    $this->_apiKey = Configuration::get('API_KEY');
}
```

I wanted to turn off the module if there is no variable. So that after the hook he does not execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any hook you can begin with:

```
if(!($this->_apiKey = Configuration::get('API_KEY')))
    return false;
```

If there is no API_KEY in configuration it will not execute the rest of the code.
EDIT:
You can disable it using in the hook.

```
if(!($this->_apiKey = Configuration::get('API_KEY')))
{
        $this->disable(false);  // true to disable for all shops
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, but I wanted to know if it was possible to disable the module globally instead of each hook. Thank you!